# Send To functionality gives empty alert window

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0

When I try to use the Send To function to send a copy of a document to a different document library in Sharepoint 2007, I get an empty alert box pop up, and the document isn't copied.

The site is in my Local Intranet security group in IE8.  The target document library is in a sub-site of site with the source document library.

**Update** After installing Windows 7 and Office 2010 on a new computer, I tried again, and this time I *was* able to move the documents as expected.  Previously I was running Office 2003, so I can only assume that this functionality for moving documents is client side, rather than server side, and is dependant on the Sharepoint.DLLs that come with Office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the target URL is correctly formatted in the Send To configuration dialog:

> 5.Under URL, type the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) (Uniform Resource
>   Locator (URL): An address that specifies a protocol (such as HTTP or
>   FTP) and a location of an object, document, World Wide Web page, or
>   other destination on the Internet or an intranet. Example:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/.) for the SharePoint library to which you
>   want to be able to copy files. For example, to copy to a specific
>   document library or to a folder within a document library, type
>   either: http://servername/sitename/libraryname or
>   http://servername/sitename/libraryname/foldername.
>
> **Important**   Do not
>   copy and paste the URL for the destination SharePoint library directly
>   from the browser into this text box because this version of the URL
>   will contain extra characters that will prevent you from being able to
>   copy a file successfully to the destination library.

Ref: [Specify a Send To destination for a library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-sharepoint-services-help/specify-a-send-to-destination-for-a-library-HA010120850.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that.  The blank box comes up for just the document library path.

Comment: Awarding answer, although the solution was to install a more recent version of Office.